# Android setImageResource NullPointerException

Tags: android, imageview, nullpointerexception

I have the following code:

```
 public class PainLogger extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener{
     ImageView image;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.acetaminophen); //**Null Pointer Here**
         ....
     }
 }
```

Here is the image in the items.xml file. (I think this is why it is null-- instead of being in the main.xml file, the imageView is in my items.xml file, although it does show up in R.id, and R.drawable)

```
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You do indeed get a NullPointerException because that widget does not exist in your main.xml file. R.* lists every single ressource in your application, so that's why you see R.id.imageView1 in it.

You should either copy the contents of your items.xml file in your main.xml, or use < include /> to include items.xml or main.xml, or just change your code logic.

If you are trying to access items in a list, you should be using a ListView in main.xml, and use an adapter. You'll find a nice tutorial about this here : http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Comment: thanks, but i have no idea how to include the image view in my main.xml file. do i just say "<include ImageView android:layout_height = "wrap...............></ImageView>/>"?

Comment: You could just copy/paste the layout in it.

Comment: oh ok, but this is what i aim to do in my app: i have a list in my main layout, and when clicked, I want to display this layout, "item.xml", which should have an imageview in it... so how would I do this from my PainLogger.java file?

Comment: You could switch to this layout using setContentView(R.layout.item) in your activity.